# Authorize is not authenticating action asp.net mvc 5 with Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have Global Filter as

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
```

My Signin Code is

```
 [AllowAnonymous,HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(UsersViewModel usermodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<UsersViewModel, Users>();
            Users model = Mapper.Map<Users>(usermodel);
            Users result = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, usermodel.Password);
            if (result != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(result, true);
                return RedirectToAction("Success", "Home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Incorrect username and/or password");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    private async Task SignInAsync(Users user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        ClaimsIdentity identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            IsPersistent = isPersistent
        }, identity);
    }
```

Now when I am signing in then its redirecting to `/Home/Success`.  Its alright I saw the cookies its also creating the authentication cookie.  However when I am trying to access `/Account/AddRole` which isnt marked as `allowannonymous`. In spite I have already authenticated . Its still redirecting me to `/Account/Login` . Which shouldn't happen . However my Authentication Startup Class for Owin is :

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => new RemsContext());
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<RemsContext>(() => new RemsContext());

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieName = "Authcookie",
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    }
```

Why its not authentication working inspite it sets the authentication cookie for Asp.net ? From Identity Framework . I m currently using Identityframework beta 2.0.1 . can someone guide why authorize in global isnt working as expected in spite I have already logged in and the authentication cookie has been set ?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? If you specify CookieSecureOption.Always then it would fail to retrieve the cookie and build identity over HTTP.